# NSPredicate to-many relationships

Tags: ios, nspredicate, one-to-many, relationship

How can I find all the categories that have subcategories with more than 1 items? 
I am using the following code, but I get "multiple to-many keys not allowed here".

Do I need to use a SUBQUERY?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Categories"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY subcategories.items > 0"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Help! :)

Comment: Use multiple NSPredicates via NSCompoundPredicate. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Comment: `items` probably is a set, try using `@count`

Answer (score 9):

Based on my experience, you should change the predicate format string in

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY subcategories.items > 0"];
```

from

```
@"ANY subcategories.items > 0"
```

into

```
@"subcategories.items.@count > 0"
```

Note that the ANY keyword needs to go as well, or you'll be querying the property the wrong way.

Comment: that raises NSInvalidArgumentException, since subcategories and items are sets.

Answer (score 3):

In your NSPredicate you should use `subcategories.items.@count >0` instead.

Sorr, that would work only if categories-subcategories wer one - to one.

Really,what you should do, is delete all the SubCategories wich have no items, I think.

Than tou should just check if there are any subcategories and it would mean that they are not empty.
`subcategories.@count >0`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Getting 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported function expression count:(subcategories.items)'. Category has a to-many relationship to Subcategories, and Sucategories to-many relationship to Items.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use one to-many relationship in a SQL backend.  This will do it, but you have to add the "back-link" into an ordered set (to preserve order if you use sorting - and uniqueness because you may get multiple subcategories pointing back to the same category).  Not ideal, but not bad, considering the limitations.

```
// Search for all subcategories with item count > 0
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Subcategory"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"items.@count > 0"];
NSError *error = nil;
// They should have an inverse relationship to their category...
// We have to iterate and insert them in to a set, but there is no additional
// disk access.
NSMutableOrderedSet *results = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSet];
[[self.projectDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Subcategory *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [results addObject:obj.category];
}];
```

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible with the SQL store.  First, let me stress that I am not anywhere close to an SQL expert, and I usually try to design my CoreData stores so that these types of queries are not necessary.  However, the following SUBQUERY works with an InMemory store, so it's a somewhat properly formatted subquery.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(subcategories, $s, $s.items.@count > 0).@count > 0"];
```

However, that predicate gives an error when using an SQL store. The docs do say there are a fair number of limitations when using predicates with SQL stores, so I'm neither surprised, nor inclined to spend too much more time researching this.

> Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed
>   to handle $s.items.@count

Comment: Just got around to trying a different approach.  Does this do it for you?

Comment: yep, thats what I am using, but I was looking to do it through subquery or @count (if there is a way) at database level. I am not sure if iteration is the most efficient way.